# Cannot read properties of undefined Provider when trying to set up ContextAPI in nextJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm having issues setting up ContextAPI on a nextjs app. I am getting this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Provider')
```

This is how I create context:

```
import React, { createContext, useState } from 'react';
const { PropContext } = createContext();
export default PropContext;

export const PropContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [username, setUsername] = useState([])
    let contextData = {
        username: username,
        setUsername: setUsername
    }
    return(
        <PropContext.Provider value={contextData} >
            { children }
        </PropContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

and in index.js:

```
export default function Home() {
  const [steps, setSteps] = useState(1);
  return (
    <>
    <PropContextProvider/>
    <div className="homeBackGround">
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <Head>
        <title>Interactive World!</title>
      </Head>
    ....
    <PropContextProvider/>
    </>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `React.createContext` actually returns the context that you need. You don't need to destructure the returned object.

You can simply do:

```js
const PropContext = createContext();
```

You can read more here if you're interested:
https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#reactcreatecontext

Moreover, you need to change the first `<PropContextProvider/>` to `<PropContextProvider>` to become an opening element (rather than a self-enclosing element). Then you can expect your child consumers to be able to access the value of the context.

Comment: I get a similar error when I try to import variables from context in another component.

So `{ username, setUsername } = useContext(Context)`

returns the error:
`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'username')`

Comment: I guess looking at your code I now see the problem. The first `<PropContextProvider/>` should become `<PropContextProvider>`. It's currently self-enclosing. Basically you currently rendering two PropContextProviders with no children.